# RJS with Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rjs, jrubyonrails

What would be the proper way to set Devise gem (ruby on rails v3) in RJS style (example: http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs)?

I usually create a create.js.erb file with alert(@error). When using devise I don't know how to properly get @error value. I would like to display all messages as javascript alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I think, to achieve this you will need to write your own controllers (inherited from devise) and views. And then add `respond_to :html, :js` to this controllers. After this, controllers will be able to respond to javascript requests and you can manage your alerts.
Read doc for how to create custom Devise views here: [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: It gets complicated when trying to display error messages :).

Comment: No one sad it would be easy :) - the reason is that you need to overrdide Devise defaults